# Jest - test for React memory leak

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have a component with a promise. I want that promise to be cancelled on unmounting (I use Bluebird to cancel the promise). I just don't know how to test that. Is there a way to test for that using Jest? I guess I can mock the promise, but I would prefer if there was a better way. Is there a way to change the warning `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.` to be an error so I can use an `expect(...).not.toThrow();`.

This is an App.js example (here I use a timeout instead of a promise):

```
import {useRef, useState} from "react";

function App() {
    const curTimeout = useRef(setTimeout(()=>{}, 0));
    const [state, setState] = useState();

    function setNewTimeout() {
        clearTimeout(curTimeout.current);

        curTimeout.current = setTimeout(()=>{
            setState(1);
        }, 1000);
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={setNewTimeout}>
            CLICK ME
        </button>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my App.test.js code:

```
import {act, fireEvent, render} from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./App";

beforeEach(() => {
  jest.useFakeTimers();
});

test("test for memory leaks", async () => {
  const {unmount, getByText} = render(<App />);

  fireEvent.click(getByText("CLICK ME"));
  unmount();

  act(()=>{
    jest.runAllTimers();
  });
});
```

The app was created with create-react-app. When I add

```
useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            clearTimeout(curTimeout.current);
        };
    }, []);
```

the test should now work.

Comment: Here's one way to "upgrade" error logs to test failures: https://github.com/textbook/impasse/blob/0048a19b4ed9a5b18d2b417dce760ec3211a8a3e/setupTests.js#L5-L17

Comment: Thanks. In the end, I decided to go with mocking the sleep promise, but it seems useful to have that as an option (maybe to use for every component).